# How to have Xcode 14 create a SwiftUI file with tab indentation

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have tab indentation set in my Text Editing -> Indentation settings and also set to tabs in my project settings in Xcode 14, however if I create a new SwiftUI file it has the indentation using spaces. If I copy and paste the text it will correctly reindent the source code with tabs, but the default source code provided in the file is always indented with spaces. How do you have Xcode set the indentation to tabs for the default source code in SwiftUI files?